# TypeError: ufunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')

Tags: python, datetime, python-xarray

I currently have a netCDF file of hourly readings from 18/07/1996 to 31/12/2006 and wish to calculate the JJA seasonal averages of the data variables. I have attempted to follow the example shown on http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/examples/monthly-means.html:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('BE_Vie.H.nc')
ds

>> <xarray.Dataset>
>> Dimensions:      (nt: 2, time: 91632, x: 1, y: 1)
>> Coordinates:
>>   * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 1996-07-18T01:00:00 ... 2006-12-31
>>     latitude     (y, x) float32 ...
>>     longitude    (y, x) float32 ...
>> Dimensions without coordinates: nt, x, y
>> Data variables:
>>     time_bounds  (time, nt) datetime64[ns] ...
>>     gpp_gb       (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     resp_p_gb    (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     resp_s_gb    (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     ftl_gb       (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     latent_heat  (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     rad_net      (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     sw_down      (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     precip       (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     t1p5m_gb     (time, y, x) float32 ...
>>     q1p5m_gb     (time, y, x) float32 ...

month_length = ds.time.dt.days_in_month
month_length

>> <xarray.DataArray 'days_in_month' (time: 91632)>
>> array([31, 31, 31, ..., 31, 31, 31])
>> Coordinates:
>>   * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1996-07-18T01:00:00 ... 2006-12-31

# Calculate the weights by grouping by 'time.season'.
weights = month_length.groupby('time.season') / month_length.groupby('time.season').sum()

# Test that the sum of the weights for each season is 1.0
np.testing.assert_allclose(weights.groupby('time.season').sum().values, np.ones(4))

# Calculate the weighted average
ds_weighted = (ds * weights).groupby('time.season').sum(dim='time')
```

However, I am met by this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-51dd727eba52> in <module>
      6 
      7 # Calculate the weighted average
----> 8 ds_weighted = (ds * weights).groupby('time.season').sum(dim='time')

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in func(self, other)
   4774                 self, other = align(self, other, join=align_type, copy=False)
   4775             g = f if not reflexive else lambda x, y: f(y, x)
-> 4776             ds = self._calculate_binary_op(g, other, join=align_type)
   4777             return ds
   4778 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in _calculate_binary_op(self, f, other, join, inplace)
   4845         else:
   4846             other_variable = getattr(other, "variable", other)
-> 4847             new_vars = {k: f(self.variables[k], other_variable) for k in self.data_vars}
   4848         ds._variables.update(new_vars)
   4849         ds._dims = calculate_dimensions(ds._variables)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
   4845         else:
   4846             other_variable = getattr(other, "variable", other)
-> 4847             new_vars = {k: f(self.variables[k], other_variable) for k in self.data_vars}
   4848         ds._variables.update(new_vars)
   4849         ds._dims = calculate_dimensions(ds._variables)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py in func(self, other)
   1987                 new_data = (
   1988                     f(self_data, other_data)
-> 1989                     if not reflexive
   1990                     else f(other_data, self_data)
   1991                 )

TypeError: ufunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')
```

How should I convert my time variable in order to make this work? Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated - thank you!!

More details about the time variable:

```
ds.time

>> <xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 91632)>
>> array(['1996-07-18T01:00:00.000000000', '1996-07-18T02:00:00.000000000',
>>        '1996-07-18T03:00:00.000000000', ..., '2006-12-30T22:00:00.000000000',
>>        '2006-12-30T23:00:16.000000000', '2006-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'],
>>       dtype='datetime64[ns]')
>> Coordinates:
>>   * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1996-07-18T01:00:00 ... 2006-12-31
>> Attributes:
>>     standard_name:  time
>>     long_name:      Time of data
>>     bounds:         time_bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be in multiplying a datetime variable by a float. When you call `(ds * weights)`, weights gets multiplied by every variable in ds. I would guess that `ds.time_bounds * weights` doesn't really make sense, and this TypeError agrees.

I'd recommend elevating time_bounds to a coordinate. Non-indexing coordinates are similar to data variables, but math operations don't affect them. See the xarray docs on [Coordinates](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html#coordinates).

Try `ds = ds.set_coords('time_bounds')` before your weighted operation.